# toDataURL function in canvas is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

I'm trying to access the toDataURL() function inside this.down.current.addEventListener in componentDidMount(), don't know why it is not accessible. Other functions like toJSON() and toSVG() are available inside this.down.current.addEventListener but canvas.toDataURL(). can anyone help me? I can access the canvas.toDataURL() outside the this.down.current.addEventListener in componentDidMount() but not inside the this.down.current.addEventListener don't know why?

```
import React from "react";
import { fabric } from "fabric";
export default class Editor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.urlFormat = this.urlFormat.bind(this);
    this.text = React.createRef();
    this.tri = React.createRef();
    this.cir = React.createRef();
    this.down = React.createRef();
  }

  urlFormat(arg) {
    let url = arg.slice(7);
    url = `https://pixabay.com/get/${url}.jpg`;
    return url;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
    fabric.Image.fromURL(this.urlFormat(window.location.search),(Img)=>{
      if (Img.width > Img.height) {
        Img.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);
        Img.top = (canvas.height - Img.scaleX * Img.height) / 2;
      } else {
        Img.scaleToHeight(canvas.height);
        Img.left = (canvas.width - Img.scaleX * Img.width) / 2;
      }
      Img.selectable = false;
      canvas.add(Img);
    });
    this.tri.current.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        fill: "white"
      });
      canvas.add(triangle);
    });
    this.cir.current.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const circle = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 50,
        fill: "blue"
      });
      canvas.add(circle);
    });
    this.down.current.addEventListener("click",() => {
      console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="view-pannel">
        <canvas id="c" width="500" height="400" />
        <div className="tools-pannel">
          <div>Add Caption</div>
          <div className="shape-bar">
            <span>
              Triangle
              <button value="triangle" ref={this.tri}>
                Add
              </button>
            </span>
            <span>
              Circle
              <button value="circle" ref={this.cir}>
                Add
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div ref={this.down}>
              Download
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");` canvas is only declared locally and is destroyed when the component's mount is over. Then when the funciton is called `canvas` doesn't exist. You likely need to make it accessible from the parent by setting it to `this.canvas`

Comment: it is still not working